# Expression expected. with eslint and react

Tags: reactjs, eslint

here is my code with a problem

```
handleXPosition(e) {
    const x = parseFloat(e.target.value);
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ position: ...prevState.position, x}));
}
```

this my state:

```
this.state = {
    position: { x: 0.5, y: 0.5 },
    rotate: 0,
    scale: 1,
    width: 250,
    height: 160,
    imageSource: '',
    editMode: false,
 };
```

my button in my jsx part:

```
<div>
    <TextField
        label="Position X"
        type="range"
        onChange={this.handleXPosition}
        inputProps={{ min: 0, max: 1, step: 0.01 }}
    />
</div>
```

i have this message dans VS code

```
[ts] Expression expected. [1109]
```

in the `...prevState.position` part.

and I do not understand

thank

Comment: How about this? Removing the brackets -> this.setState((prevState) => { position: ...prevState.position, x});

Comment: In my opinion, you don't need to reset `position` in this case because you set this key to it's previous value `this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, x }))`

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({ position: prevState.position, x }));
```

or even:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, x }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change line to following:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({ position: {...prevState.position}, x}));
```

or

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({...prevState, x}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to take out the `position` from your state, you do not need to deconstruct it :

```
handleXPosition(e) {
    const x = parseFloat(e.target.value);
    this.setState(prevState => ({ position: prevState.position, x }));
}
```

And if you want to take out every values from your previous props :

```
handleXPosition(e) {
    const x = parseFloat(e.target.value);
    this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, x }));
}
```

---

EDIT

To modify the nested `x` value, you will have to deconstruct your old object into position and only override the `x` value :

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ position: {...prevState.position, x}}));
```

Comment: with the first solution, i have not problem with eslint but my postion (x) does not change!

Comment: @VianneyBailleux Alright, I figured out was was going wrong after seeing your data structure, see the edit

Answer (score -1):

try it like this:

EDIT:

```
handleXPosition = (
    e: {
      target: { value },
    },
  ) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ position: prevState.position, x: parseFloat(value) }));
  };
```

edited the answer.

Comment: with the solution i have this error: TypeError: _ref.e is undefined